# Strange output while fitting Keras & TensorFlow 1.10.1 python 3.6.5 Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, stderr

I'm using Keras with TF, and while fitting (model.fit) very strange text is send to stderr. Like this bellow.It seems that is send after each batch.
Has anyone an idea how to stop this?
Keras 2.2.2 TensorFlow 1.10.1 python 3.6.5 Ubuntu 16.04

```
   [[1069 15315][0]...]
    [[914 15470][0]...]
    [[579 15805][0]...]
    [[1907 11840][199]...]
    [[1947 14437][0]...]
    [[1119 9491][122]...]
    [[5521 28][10736]...]
    [[10454 126][5804]...]
    [[8193 67][8065]...]
    [[3740 28][12518]...]
    [[12423 102][3837]...]
    [[16257 127][0]...]
    [[3394 0][12987]...]
    [[11256 2][5123]...]
    [[15506 2][876]...]
    [[16383 1][0]...]
    [[16383 1][0]...]
    [[4506 0][11877]...]
    [[16384 0][0]...]
    [[13702 0][2682]...]
    [[16320 0][64]...]
    [[12902 0][3482]...]
    [[16384 0][0]...]
    [[11353 0][5031]...]
    [[16384 0][0]...]
    [[16384 0][0]...]
    [[16384 0][0]...]
    [[1069 15315][0]...]
    [[914 15470][0]...]
    [[579 15805][0]...]
    [[1907 11840][199]...]
    [[1947 14437][0]...]
    [[1119 9491][122]...]
    [[5521 28][10736]...]
    [[10454 126][5804]...]
    [[8193 67][8065]...]
    [[3740 28][12518]...]
    [[12423 102][3837]...]
    [[16257 127][0]...]
    [[3394 0][12987]...]
    [[11256 2][5123]...]
    [[15506 2][876]...]
    [[16383 1][0]...]
    [[16383 1][0]...]
    [[4506 0][11877]...]
    [[16384 0][0]...]
    [[13702 0][2682]...]
    [[16320 0][64]...]
    [[12902 0][3482]...]
    [[16384 0][0]...]
    [[11353 0][5031]...]
    [[16384 0][0]...]
    [[16384 0][0]...]
    [[16384 0][0]...]
```

Comment: please add the code and the input data to your question!

Comment: @ Cut7er - you're absolutely right. When preparing minimal piece of code to reproduce error I found an old tf.Print() call in my Kreas model custom metric. Your simple advice to provide code just helped me a lot. Please close a ticket. Thank you.